# How to handle Doctrine 2's errors nicely?

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a bit of code that sometimes throw errors for different reasons. And I would like to get more informations about it. The problem is either I have nothing at all and my app break or I use try catch and get a whole bunch of stuff from xdebug_message that I can't really show the user.

Let's say I need to do a collection of object AND make sure that some argument is filled (For this case we have nullable=false in the entity). If I miss one of those two points Here is what I get with the following code :

```
// We create the event
        $event = new Entity\Event;
        $event->setType( $this->input->post( 'type' ) );
        $event->setDescription( $this->input->post( 'description' ) );

        $event->setPlace( $place );
        $event->setUser( $user );

        // We can now persist this entity:
        try
        {
            $em->persist( $event );
            $em->flush();
        }
        catch( \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e )
        {
            // Error When Persisting the Entity !!
            // 500 Internal Server Error
            // A generic error message, given when no more specific message is suitable
            $this->response( array( 'error' => $e ), 500 );
        }

        $message = array(
                        "success" => TRUE
                    );

        // Everything is fine
        $this->response( $message, 200 ); // 200 being the HTTP response code
```

In this case, it returns:

> {"error":{"xdebug_message":"

What I would like to do is that from this error message, automatically execute some function or send an explicit message to the front side for any configuration possible. I can't really use xdebug here, it is not very helpful for this purpose.

How can I get more explicit details from PHP or Doctrine itself ?

I'm working with Doctrine2 and Codeigniter 2.1 or 2 dont know.

Thanks

Comment: Why on Earth are you running XDebug in production?

Comment: I'm not on Production (or I'm not on earth I don't know..)

Comment: I'm just making some test and trying to build this nicely

Answer (score 1):

there some function give  you nice msg. like `$e->getMessage()` `$e->getCode()`